# Difference between PostgreSQL SKU Size and Storage Size(MB) in Azure ARM

Tags: postgresql, azure

I'm writing an Azure Resource Manager template for deploying and building a Web App with PostgreSQL, [using the template provided here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-webapp-linux-managed-postgresql).

Within the section for resource type *Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers* -- [documentation reference here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.dbforpostgresql/servers) -- multiple values are mentioned in regards to database size; **Sku Size**, defined as a *string*, and **storageMB**, an integer indicating the max storage allowed for a server.

Nowhere in the linked documentation is an example given for exactly what string is needed for Sku Size. What should be entered here and how does it differ in definition from the database storageMB?

**Resource JSON Tree**

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "type": "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers",
  "apiVersion": "2017-12-01",
  "sku": {
    "name": "string",
    "tier": "string",
    "capacity": "integer",
    "size": "string",
    "family": "string"
  },
  "properties": {
    "version": "string",
    "sslEnforcement": "string",
    "storageProfile": {
      "backupRetentionDays": "integer",
      "geoRedundantBackup": "string",
      "storageMB": "integer"
    },
    "createMode": "string"
  },
  "location": "string",
  "tags": {},
  "resources": []
}
```

**Definitions**
*Sku Size (String, Not Required)* - The size code, to be interpreted by resource as appropriate.
*storageMB (Integer, Not Required)* - Max storage allowed for a server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*updated to answer the actual question*

Digging into the [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/postgresql/servers/create) it appears that this is not required to create a resource.

looking through the Azure Cli [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/fffddf3e11ca67c1cd885347847daa1b173f0605/src/command_modules/azure-cli-rdbms/azure/cli/command_modules/rdbms/_params.py) size is referenced as ignored. references to size are removed altogether in the current version of Cli.

it is difficult to say without digging into the versions of all of the above, but this suggests that it is an artifact that is no longer used, but has yet to be purged from the API, and hence the documentation (since that documentation is automated from the API)

---

This is all very badly documented! - however it is possible to dig through and figure out what goes where

looking [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/quickstart-create-server-database-azure-cli) it says -

> The sku-name parameter value follows the convention {pricing tier}_ {compute generation} _{vCores} as in the examples below:

While [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-pricing-tiers) will give you the sizing

```
Compute generation  Gen 4, Gen 5    Gen 4, Gen 5    Gen 5
vCores  - - - -  - 1, 2 - 2, 4, 8, 16, 32   - 2, 4, 8, 16
Memory per vCore    2 GB    5 GB    10 GB
```

(its not a great table! best look at the original on the link!)

Pricing tiers are

- basic - B
- general - GP
- memory optimised - MO

so for a basic, 1 core, generation 4, you would use B_Gen4_1 - similarly for a memory optimised, generation 5, with 16 cores, you would use MO_Gen5_16

This page also specifies the storage limits for each SKU

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However according to the documentation I linked, an example of 'B_Gen4_1' is Sku Name, not Sku Size

Comment: @Xenidious it seems my brain took a wander whilst getting grumpy at the lousy documentation of that! - it isn't a much better answer, but I have updated.

Answer (score 0):

Sku_Size is the number of cores allocated to the instance, whereas disk size is the amount of HDD allocated to the instance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/postgresql/servers/create#sku

I was unable to find an enumeration of those anywhere in the docs, but you can kinda guess from other sources:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/postgresql/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-pricing-tiers

ps. [this](https://github.com/Azure/Moodle/pull/68/files) also gives strong ideas for sku and such